# Process Builder Record Creation

Tags: process-builder

I created the Process Builder and selected
**when a record is created or edited**
 under Start the process

The action was to create a record but in my case the process builder is working fine but it's only creating a record when it's edited for the first time.
It is supposed to created the record when ever it is edited meeting the conditions mentioned.
Can someone help me in fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you check "Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?" under the Advanced filter condition, it will only execute the associated actions when the record did *not* meet the requirements before and then *did* meet the requirements after. This prevents the situation where actions are performed because of an unrelated edit. If you want the records to be created on every edit, you must **uncheck** this box (the default behavior).

Comment: Thank You for the solution.

Comment: Here's one more issue.